# My jquery code will not work if included as a .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written html/css code and then added another file to include the jquery library and my own js code (in the file `scripts.js`).

My code does not work if I keep it in the separate scripts.js file, but it does work if I apply it in the `<scripts></script>` element within `index.html`.

Why is this and how can I solve the problem?

**My HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Hartmeting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="titel">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </header>
        <!-- Menu -->
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#intro"> Introductie </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Manual -->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Intro Slide -->
            <article id="intro">
                <h2>Introductie</h2>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Intro Afbeelding"/>
                </figure>
                <p>Zonder moeite je hart meten? Dat kan...</p>
            </article>

            <!-- Slide 1 -->
            <article id="probleem">
                <h2>Het Probleem</h2>
                <figure>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Eerste Afbeelding"/>
                </figure>
                <p>Het probleem uitleggen</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <a href="#wrapper"> To the top! </a>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Browser Console Log:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'. Expected an opening '(' before a
>   function's parameter list.

But it does work, if I do it like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Hartmeting</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('content').hide();
            });
        </script>
    </head>       
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header id="titel">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </header>

            <!-- Menu -->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#intro"> Introductie </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Manual -->
            <div id="content">
                <!-- Intro Slide -->
                <article id="intro">
                    <h2>Introductie</h2>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Intro Afbeelding"/>
                    </figure>
                    <p>Zonder moeite je hart meten? Dat kan...</p>
                </article>

                <!-- Slide 1 -->
                <article id="probleem">
                    <h2>Het Probleem</h2>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" , alt="Eerste Afbeelding"/>
                    </figure>
                    <p>Het probleem uitleggen</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <a href="#wrapper"> To the top! </a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: is your javascript file in your /css directory?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function){` that looks like a syntax error. Neither should be working if that is how your code is actually written

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, Console says syntax error. (Added that to my story) thanks

Comment: Compare it to the documents version that does work http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems to be right (well, yes, you already fixed that though). Yet your jQuery selector is wrong. In order to hide an html element through it's id you need the `#`prefix. That being said, your `.hide()` should look like this:

```
  $('#content').hide();
```

And also, here's the whole snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').hide();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ua9tg/)

Comment: This works, but strangely enough if I add:                                                      var article = $('#intro').first();
$(article.first).show();  It won't work. Why is this?

Comment: It does for me. Maybe your var declaration is wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ua9tg/1/

Comment: This is what I currently have: https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ua9tg/2/ I need it to hide everything and than show only '#intro'

Comment: I see. Yes, that won't work. `show()` and `hide()` do set `display: none` to either true or false (depending on the function you use). Your `#intro` element is inside of your `#content`. You may hide `#intro` on its own or rethink your problem. At least I guess this would deserve a separate question (or at least some google research) since your initial answer should have been answered. Just a short snippet of what would be possible (even though that's a really bad example) > https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ua9tg/6/

Comment: An upvote and selecting the right answer would be nice. At least think about Kevins answer. It's pretty much the same, just without some explanations, but he answered a few minutes before me. At the end it's up to you. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing the parenthesis after function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#content").hide();
});
```